# CR2 Photos showing the correct file size for a photo but cannot open them or convert to jpeg?? Need help repairing

Tags: images, repair, photos

I was taking photos the other day at Glacier National Park and halfway through the afternoon the previews stopped showing up on my camera. After inserting the card into my computer I found that the second half of the batch were all the proper size for a photo but are giving me the error "may be damaged or use a file format that is unrecognizable".

I've tried every photo recovery software I could find and they all do not even recognize the files. I tried downloading iHex to possibly remove a damaged header but the photos show up showing only Fs' on every line (I've never used this program before so may be user error). I have not done anything to the SD card itself besides make a copy of the photos on my computer. I also tried converting to JPG with no luck.

Any ideas?

I've uploaded 4 photos:
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0Bwvjk4sXOF52MUtpZXY1TTFFcDQ&usp=sharing

7829 is the last good photo, 7830 is where something went wrong, and 7831/32 are screwed.

Thanks for any help you can give me!!

Comment: You don't have a back up? If you only see F's , then that's what it is! F'd!! :( Also, how do you know the files are the proper size? Try adding one to a compressed folder (zip it) and see if the file size changes dramatically

Comment: Thanks for the tip, when I compress it goes from a 16MB file to 16kb... Sounds like all hope is lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've said the hex editor shows all F's which makes me think the file size it's showingg is not correct.

A good way to tell if the file is actually what you think is to compress it. I once had a ~2GB .pst file, adding it to WinZip and it was 64kb or so...

If you try this and the file size is greatly different then it shows the file isn't what you think it. Other than a back up I don't think you've got any hope of restoring these files, I'm sorry.

Comment: Yep just gave that a go and that exact situation happened, 16 MB to 16 KB